# Writing line integral as 1-form

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

If $F: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^n $ is a vector field and $\phi : [a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ is a continously differentiable path we defined the integral of $F$ along $\phi$ as $\int_{\phi} F = \int_a^b F(\phi(t)) \cdot \phi^\prime(t)dt$. Now we said that one can also write this as: $$\int_{\phi} F=\int_a^b \sum_{i=1}^n F_i(\phi(t))\phi^\prime_i(t)dt=\int_\phi \sum_{i=1}^n F_i(x)dx_i $$by substituting $\phi(t)=x$. This is not clear to me. To me it looks like he used the substitution rule in one dimension for a vector, why can one do this? Also i dont understand what the integration bound $\phi$ is supposed to mean in this context.
I appreciate any help & answers:)

Comment: $d\omega = F_1 dx_1 + F_2 dx_2+\cdots+F_n dx_n$. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

Writing $\int_\phi {\bf F}$ is a notation: you are integrating along the path. By definition this is $\int_a^b {\bf F}(\phi(t))\cdot \phi'(t)\,{\rm d}t$. By definition of the dot product in $\Bbb R^n$ this is $\int_a^b \sum F_i(\phi(t))\phi_i'(t)\, {\rm d}t$. Since integrals are additive, this reads $\sum \int_a^b F_i(\phi(t))\phi_i'(t)\, {\rm d}t$.

Now we can restrict our attention to the little integrals $\int_a^b F_i(\phi(t))\phi_i'(t)\,{\rm d}t$. These are integrals on $\Bbb R$, and here $x_i = \phi_i(t)$ gives ${\rm d}x_i= \phi_i'(t)\,{\rm d}t$.

There's no harm in thinking ${\bf x}= \phi(t) \implies {\rm d}{\bf x} = \phi'(t)\,{\rm d}t$, it is essentialy what we're doing in the end. $\int_\phi {\bf F}$ is a shorthand for $\int_\phi {\bf F} \cdot {\rm d}{\bf x} = \int_a^b {\bf F}(\phi(t))\cdot \phi'(t)\,{\rm d}t$.